# Java Instant.toEpochMilli() & Javascript Date.now() not in sync

Tags: javascript, java, date, networking, time

I am trying to collect performance metrics on the client for streaming pricing data coming from a server process over websockets. The server is written in Java and the client is an Angular UI application. Both the server and the client are written in-house and are within the same organisation's network. The data goes stale in 250 ms and we measure several parameters one of which is network lag.

The server stamps the sentAtTime on the message header just before it leaves the server using Java's Instant.toEpochMilli(). The client records the receivedAtTime using Javascript's Date.now() as soon as it picks the message up.

I then calculate time over the wire as `NetworkLag = receivedAtTime - sentAtTime`

Surprisingly the lag is negative sometimes upto -30 ms which is baffling me. I have checked that the maths isn't wrong and I also get positive lag values. The only explanation I can think of is that the clocks on the server and client are somehow are not in sync. Have others seen something like this and what are the steps I could take to remediate the situation.

Comment: "*the clocks on the server and client are somehow are not in sync*." Exactly. "*what are the steps I could take to remediate*". There are none. If a client wants to tell you their local time is Jan 1st 1970, they're welcome to do that. That's not 52 years of lag. That's the inherent untrustworthiness of the client-server relationship. You can't force a client to provide an accurate timestamp.

Comment: And anyway, network lag over the internet is something you can't do anything about, so why do you care? What are you going to do, build a competing network? The only performance metric that really matters is how long it took your server to process a given request.

Comment: If you want test lag, why not have the client ping the server?

Comment: Measure the network lag both ways and average. Then the different clocks will be compensated for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to figure out the time difference between server and client despite the effects of network lag. Check out how NTP works. It synchronizes system clocks over the laggy internet and intends to resolve down to milliseconds deviation.

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol):

> NTP is intended to synchronize all participating computers to within a
> few milliseconds of Coordinated Universal Time (UTC). It uses
> the intersection algorithm, a modified version of Marzullo's
> algorithm, to select accurate time servers and is designed to mitigate
> the effects of variable network latency.

Comment: NTP is not something that's realistic on a web server-client relationship. If I access StackOverflow and Twitter and they both want to sync my clock to them, who I do choose? What do they do if I simply refuse?

Comment: I did not suggest to use your webserver as NTP reference. But there is an algorithm that can figure out the network lag. If NTP can implement it, so can Rahul for his application.

Comment: Any algorithm that relies on clients acting in good faith is open to manipulation.

Comment: Unless it is a hacked, where should the manipulation come from? 'Both the server and the client are written in-house and are within the same organisation's network.'

Comment: Oh, he edited that in more recently than I read the question.